# AJAX'ed mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in

Tags: jquery

Can someone help to figure out why this http://khine.3b1.org/countries.htm works fine, but when i try to load the list via AJAX, it works, but there are some bugs http://khine.3b1.org/countries-ajax.htm

1/. the 'arrow' is not displayed when there are sub-sections
2/. key navigation does not seem to work correctly (it only works after i have used the mouse)

To test please choose 'United Kingdom, Wales' and then any county.

thanks for any advice

norman

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking to use mcdropdown with JSON. Didn't had full success but made a little progress.

Try using this options .mcDropdown("#locations",options);

```
var options = { select: function (value, display) {
                   $(".mcdropdown_menu > .mc_root.mc_hover").trigger("mouseover");
                   $(".mcdropdown_menu > .mc_root > ul > li.mc_hover").trigger("mouseover");
                       },
                 allowParentSelect: true
              }
```

And after the recreate of the mcDropdown in the ajax call:

```
                    $("#country").mcDropdown().focus();
```

But you need to press twice the arrow key to see the contents of the parent.

Comment: hi diogo, thank you for this. i also have http://khine.3b1.org/ff/ff.html but is not yet perfect. it seems very slow as well, as it is making too many ajax calls.